# What does 老铁 mean?

Tags: meaning

I found some people call others 老铁. What does this mean? Does it mean friend? I can't find this usage in any dictionaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

老铁 is a term that originates from Northeastern Mandarin (東北話), and means "bro" or "close friend". Slang from regional dialects often spill over into mainstream Chinese and get adopted by everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Brief extension:

> 老: literally means old, but by adding in front of a pronoun, it produces a sense of intimacy.

**Example:**

老王 (*Mr. Wang*, but most likely someone you are famaliar with)

老哥 (*buddy*)

> 铁: literally "iron", describes a strong relationship.

**Example:**

铁哥们 (*buddy*, has a stronger relationship than "老哥")

巴铁 (some Chinese use this term to describe the relationship between China and Pakistan (巴基斯坦))

**Note:**
The word is an internet slang derived from Dongbei dialect, so of course you can't find any definition in a formal dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

According to [baidu](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%80%81%E9%93%81/2914018)

> 中文名: 老铁
>
> 外文名: sidekick/buddy

Which also fits with the use of it as far as I have seen it

Answer (score 1):

Actually in Northeast China, 老铁 means a secret lover. Later the meaning turned into 'friend'.

Answer (score 0):

You can think 老铁 just means "guys" or "buddy"  in english

Answer (score 0):

more close than guys.

but a little 调侃

Answer (score -1):

Means Pakistan and China are Iron Brothers. It’s signifies the relationship between the 2 countries.

Comment: Welcome to [chinese.se]! I'm not sure how Pakistan figures into this ...